# Chain link Aggregator v3 Interface error?

Tags: remix, chainlink

I am following a tutorial that implements Chain Link's Aggregator V3 Interface, but it seems the code is not interacting properly with its import. [image]Attempting to deploy on Remix brings up the error pictured below:

Here is the code I'm using to call it:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.6.6 < 0.9.0;

contract FundMe {

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    

    }

}
```

I posted on ethereum stack exchange with no luck, and also contacted Chain Link (they recommended Stack overflow). Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you (:

Comment: Are you selecting the "FundMe" contract in the "Deploy and run transactions" tab, selectbox "Contract"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when an abstract or interface contract is selected to deploy, and many imports are abstract or interfaces.

Ensure you select the correct contract in the "Deploy and Run Transactions" tab. If you want to choose the "FundMe" contract, make sure it is selected and not some other contract.
[image: FundMe in contract selector]